# Using webcam connected to MacBook inside a Docker container

Tags: video, webcam, docker

Has anybody figured out yet how to use an external webcam which is connected to a MacBook inside a Docker container?

I read that I have to pass this flag `--device /dev/video0` to docker run, but I have a MacBook and there is no `/dev/video0`.

Host Machine: `MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012)`
External Webcam: `Logitech C922 Pro Stream`
Docker container: `wusuopu/python-opencv3-dlib:py3.5`

PS: I do not have an iSight camera anymore, I took it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/faqs/#what-is-the-benefit-of-hyperkit this is not possible.

Similar question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023827/accessing-usb-webcam-hosted-on-os-x-from-a-docker-container

And possible answer is stream the camera into the container using ffmpeg according to a comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960828/webcam-streaming-from-mac-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

This article claims to get it working. It's a bit more than I'm willing to try so I'm still searching, but maybe someone wants to try it out: https://medium.com/@jijupax/connect-the-webcam-to-docker-on-mac-or-windows-51d894c44468

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.